# What is type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<dynamic>?'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

Can someone let me know how to call a function as a stream in StreamBuilder? While trying so im getting this error as **type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Stream?'**.

I'm using stream builder so as to listen to the realtime changes to a specfic field value in the collection. Please let me know where im doing wrong in the code below, and what changes do i need to make for working of this snippet.

**Here is the code :**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Display extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DisplayState createState() => _DisplayState();
}

class _DisplayState extends State<Display> {
  final CollectionReference student_details =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('students');
  final CollectionReference tutor_details =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("tutors");
  final CollectionReference CollectionAttendanceDetails =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('attendance');

  display() async {
    var tCT;
    var id = await student_details
        .doc("m2Hdo5eejKWfIYlD2ZJvjYepWQh2")
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      return value.data()['tutorid'];
    });
    return id;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: display(),
          builder: (_, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
            return Container(
              child: Text(snapshot.data),
            );
          }),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't do this: "stream: display(),".  You should be calling display() once in initState and store it into a state var, then referencing that state var in the StreamBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Ha bro actually display() function is not a stream.

It will be a future that will return a value at one time.

But as a stream u provided display()

convert it to futurebuilder or else firebase firestore gives a funtion that listens to realtime changes

Comment: yes i tried using FutureBuilder it works fine,, but how can i use StreamBuilder for the same requirement? The only problem with FutureBuilder is the changes only get displayed on refreshing.